# Fixing a bathroom vent exhaust going only into attic

Tags: bathroom, attic, vent

First, the facts:

1. We live in Western Oregon (lots of moisture)
2. Home was built in 1979
3. Bathroom exhaust fans are vented into attic
4. I like to do things once and do it right
   I am planning on venting the exhaust outside

Questions:

1. If I vent the exhaust to an outside wall, should I place the vent high up on the wall so it is protected by the roof?  But will I get moisture buildup on bottom of the eave?
2. Should I place the exhaust vent lower on the outside wall?  It will not be as protected by the eave.
3. What type of vent should I use?  Is it different than a dryer vent?

Answer (score 1):

The vent should not be placed directly under the eave.  The external cover of the vent when mounted on the wall protects the vent from rain.
Standard galvanized duct piping is used.  Yes, it is the same as the vent duct used for dryer.  You would just use the same ducting type that is vested to the attic.  
Exact placement on the exterior wall is also depend on where you route the duct in your attic. 
1. Will it block storage space
2. How will you suspend it
3. On the rafters.
This is a picture of vents on the exterior wall.  The vent ducts are round, the cover is a rectangle cap

[image]

Comment: The straighter the run, the better the ventilation will be.+